# Android Xamarin Views losing properties after Inflating?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to format an image over text.  I can achive this with margins and other hacks code.  I would rather do it the right way with a relative view.

Below is the code I'm using in the adapter add the view and change the text.

When the view renders the view doesn't have any formats i applied in the xml.  Am i missing something?  Do properties get wiped when a layout is inflated?

```
foreach (var ball in message.balls) {
    LinearLayout numberholder = new LinearLayout (context);
    LayoutInflater inflaterball = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    View vballlayout = inflaterball.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ball, null);
    if (ball != null) {  
    TextView tv = vballlayout.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textball);
    tv.Text = ball.number;
    }
}
```

This is how the imageview/textview looks before it goes in the view. [image]

After[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/ball"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bgball"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yellowball" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textball"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="20"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bgball"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/bgball"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/bgball"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bgball"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the target version fixes it for the new phones

android:targetSdkVersion="18"